# Ti-Nspire CX CAS: clear home screen, clc-clear equivalent in Matlab

Tags: calculator, ti-basic, ti-nspire

I am writing some simple programms which I am running in scratchpad by calling the name of the programme. I have developed a little script to print all the results at the end of the execution, but I cannot find some way to purge scratchpad before the beginning of the script? Something like 'clear' followed by 'clc' in Matlab.

Thanks in advance.

Ale N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TI-nspire version of TI-Basic is very limited in the I/O category, it only has four I/O functions.  TI-Basic has no clear function like other versions of TI-Basic do.  It is probably possible using other languages, but not using TI-Basic.